# Grab objects in Unity like half life 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing a little, but I do not really understand the scripts. I want grab objects ingame like portal or half life 2 and I was trying to code a little script for that action. I made this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;

public class PIckUp : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform theDest;

    void OnKeyDown()
    {

        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = false;
        this.transform.position = theDest.position;
        this.transform.parent = GameObject.Find("Destination").transform;

    }

    void OnKeyUp()
    {

        this.transform.parent = null;
        GetComponent<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
    }

    private void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            OnKeyDown();
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
        {
            OnKeyUp();
        }

    }

}
```

I attach this script to empty object called Destination, when I add a component in grabbable object in "theDest" I target Destination. If i press F all objects are flying i no need aim to them and deform all boxes too i leave here a picture.

[image]

[image]

I dont find a easy solution, i follow this scripts but are to complex for me and i dont understand how use them or how attach them to a player or object.

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1459773/picking-upholding-objects-portal-style.html

Comment: The main problem in your script is that every pickup is waiting for the key presses.  When you press F, everything tries to be picked up.  I looked at the scripts you linked to, it seems fine.  Make 2 scripts named the same as the class names, copy the code into each of those.  Attach the player script to your player, and the pickup script on all of your pickup items.  The only omission is the interface, which is explained in the post.  Add that interface to the pickup script and you should be good to go test.

Comment: I will try then and thanks for explain how attach it. i am a little bit lost in this.

Answer (score 2):

Well the thing is each and every object in the entire scene with this script attached will react to the key press.

I would rather

- put all your objects you want to be able to pick on a certain [Layer](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) e.g. "Pickable"
- make sure they all have colliders
- **Never** parent `Rigidbody`, rather use [Joints](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Joints.html) e.g. [`ConfigurableJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Configurable.html) could be useful here, you can completely customize it and use e.g. it's connectedAnchor in order to force the object to move towards you
- have a kinematic rigidbody on "theDest" so we can use it as anchor for the joint
- have a collider on "theDest" so that we can check distances between colliders

Additional to the layer I would also use a dedicated script like

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpringJoint))]
public class Pickable : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody rigidbody;
    public Rigidbody Rigidbody => rigidbody;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rigidbody && !TryGetComponnet<Rigidbody>(out rigidbody))
        {
            Debug.LogError("This component requires a Rigidbody!", this);
        }
    }

    public void MarkActive(bool active)
    {
        // Your customerhod for marking an object the currently active one
        // e.g. change its color, add outline etc
    }
}
```

This fulfills three purposes

- allows to check if hit object even **is** pickable
- precached components so we don't need `GetComponent` over and over again
- can implement additional behavior such as the mark active visualization

And then have only one single script **on your player** and use e.g.

```
public class PIckUpController : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody theDest;

    // Adjust this in the Inspector, select your Layer(s) that should be Pickable
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask pickableLayer;

    // Maximum range for picking objects in units
    // only Pickable objects within this range can be grabbed
    [SerializeField] private float range = 1;

    // How fast to attract picked objects
    [SerializeField] private float dragSpeed = 1;

    private Pickable currentHit;
    private Pickable currentPicked;
    private ConfigurableJoint currentJoint;

    private void Awake ()
    {
        if(!theDest) theDest = GameObject.Find("Destination"). GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void PickUp()
    {
        currentJoint = currentHit.AddComponent<ConfigurableJoint>();
        // Todo Completely customizable behavior

        currentPicked = currentHit;
    }

    void Release()
    {
        Destroy(currentJoint);

        // TODO optional give it some impulse to throw it away here e.g.
        // (Have to tweak the values of course)
        currentPicked.Rigidbody.AddExplosionForce(10, theDest.position, 1f, 0.5f, ForceMode.Impulse));
        
        currentPicked = null;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // Have we already picked up something?
        if(!currentPicked)
        {
            // No -> we chekc if we are pointing on any object
            // within the range
            var ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out var hit, range, pickableLayer)
            {
                // yes -> get the Pickable component
                if(hit.gameObject.TryGetComponent<Pickable>(out var hitPickable))
                {
                    // Is it a different one than the one we already have?
                    if(hitPickable != currentHit)
                    {
                        // yes -> deselect the current one
                        if(currentHit)
                        {
                        currentHit.MarkActive(false);
                        }

                        // And store and select the new one
                        currentHit = hitPickable;
                        currentHit.MarkActive(true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // If there is no Pickable component we hit something else
                    // -> deselect and forget the current hit
                    if(currentHit)
                    {
                        currentHit.MarkActive(false);
                        currentHit = null;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // We don't hit anything
                // -> deselect and forget the current hit
                if(currentHit)
                {
                    currentHit.MarkActive(false);
                    currentHit = null;
                }
            }

            // Do we have a current hit?
            if(currentHit)
            {
                // yes and pressing F -> pick it up
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
                {
                    PickUp();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // We already have picked up something
            // of release F -> release object
            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.F))
            {
                Release();
            }
            else
            {
                // Todo e.g. make the object move towards the "theDest"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This one is the main responsible and does

- shoot a [`Raycast`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to check which object you are pointing at
- can additionally (optional) store and mark the currently hit object (as far as I remember HL2 marks them with an outline)
- controls the pickup and release of objects